# Word for tower used for keeping watch by security

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

What word can I use for a tower where security personnel stand to keep watch on an area?

Comment: Could we have more context? How do you plan to use the word? In a medieval novel? A modern account of prison life?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> All along the [watchtower](http://www.wordnik.com/words/watchtower)
>
> Princes kept the view

<sup>[Dylan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Along_the_Watchtower)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Lookout tower

Watch tower

Post

Answer (score 3):

Guard Tower is another useful symonym - it conveys a more spefically military meaning than watchtower or lookout post.

Answer (score 2):

Still not a single word, but:
    sentry tower

Answer (score 2):

Analogous to previously-suggested sentry tower, watchtower, and lookout tower is *[guard tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_tower)*, "a general term for any military tower providing vigilance, and henceforth guarding a certain area".  Some more-specific terms include *[barbican](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barbican)* ("A tower at the entrance to a castle or fortified town", "A temporary wooden tower built for defensive purposes", etc.) and *[bartizan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bartizan)* or *[bartisan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bartisan)* ("A parapet with battlements projecting from the top of a tower in a castle or church") and of course *[turret](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/turret)*.