# What word describes a specific place

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to know the exact word in English for "place or building from which there is an unobstructed view of the surroundings and intended for observation".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call those high areas that give you a full view of the city?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161845/what-do-you-call-those-high-areas-that-give-you-a-full-view-of-the-city) Also see [Word for tower used for keeping watch by security](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68196/word-for-tower-used-for-keeping-watch-by-security)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***watchtower***

> A tower built to create an elevated observation point.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/watchtower)

Watchtowers are seen in National Parks, where they are used as observation points for fire-watch. They are also seen in most prisons, for obvious reasons, as well as on the borders of countries whose oppressive regimes do not allow citizens to emigrate.

Comment: Sorry for posting an answer to a dupe...it did not show when I did basic research i.e. text + SE c/p google...and it made me think of Jimi.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not a physical building, you can call it a "lookout" or a "lookout point".

From the [Collins Learner Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lookout):

> A lookout is a place from which you can see clearly in all directions.

Comment: Or _view point_ (usually with space if written). That's the literal source of metaphorical _viewpoint_, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Especially in Victorian England, towers known as **prospect towers** were built so that landowners had a commanding view over their (and neighbours') demesnes:

> *prospect tower.* Tall building on high ground commanding a view, [also] called a look-out or standing tower.

[[Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/education/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/prospect-tower)]

They were often follies, little used as stairs were steep. They were less purposeful than watchtowers, which were (and are) used to detect enemies (invaders, fire ...).

As an example, the Wainhouse Tower in Halifax is listed as the world's tallest folly, though it was used as an observation point in the Second World War. Originally designed as an ornate chimney, it was quickly repurposed as a monument and viewing platform.

*Belvedere* is a related term, though this can also mean a gazebo in the sense of an area on top of an otherwise standard building intended to give wide views.

Answer (score 1):

A ***scenic overlook*** is one option to describe a location (often natural) with a good view of the surrounding countryside, to be enjoyed for recreation. It describes an elevated location that used specifically for enjoying the view. It somewhat implies a naturally occurring viewpoint from a mountaintop or ridge, so it would not typically describe a building erected specifically to be a lookout. One might find a scenic overlook along a hiking trail or along a highway.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **Coign of vantage**

> a place from which it is easy or possible to see something:

*Their position gave them a panoramic coign of vantage.*

[Cambridge]

Please note that this need not necessarily be a physical place.